# Kubernetes Cluster "healthz check failed" on macos

Tags: kubernetes

I cloned the kubernetes/kubernetes github repository and followed the given tasks to run the kubernetes cluster locally like

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/k8s.io
cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
cd kubernetes
make
```

and my startup `hack/local-up-cluster.sh` is failing with

```
Waiting for apiserver to come up
!!! [0524 22:38:39] Timed out waiting for apiserver:  to answer at https://127.0.0.1:6443/healthz; tried 60 waiting 1 between each
check apiserver logs: /tmp/kube-apiserver.log
Cleaning up...
```

My logs can be found here: https://gist.github.com/PascalKu/6f671a45385d685228a269c0bcab00f4

Comment: Can you please check again by setting `WAIT_FOR_URL_API_SERVER=120; MAX_TIME_FOR_URL_API_SERVER=5; hack/local-up-cluster.sh`?

Comment: Also tried your command but it still says "!!! [0525 04:37:31] Timed out waiting for apiserver:  to answer at https://127.0.0.1:6443/healthz; tried 60 waiting 1 between each"...

Comment: Now it looks like the 8080 apiserver port is available but the 6443 one (which needs to be exposed for the check) is not available?

Comment: I think my problem is

# WARNING: For DNS to work on most setups you should export API_HOST as the docker0 ip address,
API_HOST=${API_HOST:-localhost}
API_HOST_IP=${API_HOST_IP:-"127.0.0.1"} but I dont have an docker0 interface on mac.

Comment: "if failures occur, retry as root." Have you tried running it as Root?  I have just build k8s on Debian node i have on GCP. Installed: Go, Docker, make and gcc.  No issues at all.